# About Jordan Form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

For a $A\in M_n({\bf C})$ with a minimal polynomial $m(x) = (x-c)^n$

then we have a Jordan form wrt some basis $$ A=\left(
                                \begin{array}{ccccc}
                                  c & 1 & 0 & \cdots &0 \\
                                  0 & c & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
                                  \vdots & & &  \ddots &  \vdots \\
                                  & &  &  &  &\\
                                  0&0 & & \cdots & c
                                \end{array}
                              \right) $$

**Question** : If $C \in M_8({\bf C})$, where $C$ has a
Jordan with ${\rm diag}\ (A,B)$ and $$ A=\left(
                                \begin{array}{cccc}
                                  c & 1 & 0   &0 \\
                                  0 & c & 1  & 0\\
                                  0 &  0 &c & 0 \\
                                  0 & 0 & 0 &c
                                \end{array}
                              \right),\ B=\left(
                                \begin{array}{cccc}
                                  d & 1 & 0   &0 \\
                                  0 & d & 0  & 0\\
                                  0 &  0 &d & 0 \\
                                  0 & 0 & 0 & d
                                \end{array}
                              \right) $$
what is minimal polynomial for $C$ ? And is there a polynomial
$p(x)\in {\bf C}[x]$ s.t. $$ p(C) = {\rm diag}\ (cI,dI),\ I\in
M_4({\bf C})$$

Comment: For your first question, did you think about constant polynomials?

Comment: Sorry. I eddited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Question 2, the minimal polynomial (if $c\ne d$) the minimum polynomial is $p(x)=(x-c)^3(x-d)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $p(x) = m(x) + c$.

It is also possible to choose an example without constant term, by rescaling $m(x)$.

Comment: Thank you. But from your answer, this case in fact is easy case. So I asked again by more complicated case.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, $p=c$ will do fine. If you want a non-constant polynomial just add any multiple of $m$. If you want a zero constant term, one must distinguish the case $c=0$, for which $m=x^n$ itself already has constant term$~0$ and produces $m[A]=0=cI$, and cases with $c\neq0$ for which you can use the nonzero constant term $(-c)^n$ of $m$ to kill the constant term $c$: one can take $p=c+(-c)^{-n+1}m$.

For the second question one must distinguish the case $c=d$, for which the problem is like the first question (mut with minimal polynomial $m(x)=(x-c)^3$). When $c\neq d$ the minimal polynomials $m_A=(x-c)^3$ and $m_B=(x-d)^2$ are coprime, so the system of congruences $p\equiv c\pmod{m_A}$, $p\equiv d\pmod{m_B}$ has a solution by the Chinese remainder theorem, unique modulo the least common multiple $m_Am_B$. Again one can achieve a zero constant term if desired: if $cd=0$ then this is already the case because of one of the congruences solved for, and otherwise the nonzero constant term $-c^3d^2$ of $m_Am_B$ can be employed to make the constant term of$~p$ zero.